# What is the difference between the following pattern in xsd?

Tags: xsd, design-patterns

The patterns are,

```
    1. <xsd:pattern value = "[0-9][0-9]*"/>
```

and

```
    2. <xsd:pattern value = "[0-9]*"/>
```

it produce the same result. So what is the difference between them? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first one will match 1 or more digits. The second one will match 0 or more digits.

The `*` character means that the previous thing can be repeated 0 or more times for the pattern to be matched.

So, `[0-9][0-9]*` means "match 1 digit, followed by 0 or more digits", whereas `[0-9]*` means "match 0 or more digits (which means that the empty string will be matched as well)".

Answer (score 0):

The first pattern says, the first two characters have to be one of 0 to 9 and the rest anything, but the second pattern says the first character has to be 0 to 9 and the rest can be anything.

Comment: Not quite - you're off by one. The patterns match 1+ or 0+ characters respectively.

Answer (score 0):

They don't mean the same thing at all, but they both would pass where there are digits in the string.

[0-9]* will match strings without any digits at all, even empty strings, while [0-9][0-9]* requires at least one digit.